# Split a comma-separated string into a flat array without separating double quoted substrings

Tags: php, arrays, csv, split, delimited

How to explode this array value:

```
$row = array(
[0] = 1,1,Carlyle,Rogers,1,"Carlyle, Rogers",0000-00-00,,carlyle.rogers@stafford-trust.com,,non premium)
```

I tried this code

```
$values         =   explode(',', $row[0]);
```

and give me this wrong output:

```
Array (
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 1
   [2] => Carlyle
   [3] => Rogers
   [4] => 1
   [5] => "Carlyle
   [6] => Rogers"
   [7] => 0000-00-00
   [8] => 
   [9] => carlyle.rogers@stafford-trust.com
   [10] => 
   [11] => non premium
)
```

What I want is to Output must be like this one:

```
Array (
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 1
   [2] => Carlyle
   [3] => Rogers
   [4] => 1
   [5] => "Carlyle, Rogers"
   [6] => 0000-00-00
   [7] => 
   [8] => carlyle.rogers@stafford-trust.com
   [9] => 
   [10] => non premium
)
```

Comment: Why do you explode the array?

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `explode` like that because your input seems to be [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)-formatted and `explode` knows nothing about that "format". Use [`str_getcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) instead:

```
$values = str_getcsv($row[0]);
```